# How do i reduce the cost of this query while keeping the query results the same?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I have the below query running on a postgres and sqlserver DB (Use top for SQL server). The sorting of the "change_sequence" value is causing a high cost in my query, is there any way to reduce the cost but maintain the same results?

Query:

```sql
SELECT tablename, 
       CAST(primary_key_values AS VARCHAR), 
       primary_key_fields, 
       CAST(min_sequence AS NUMERIC), 
       _changed_fieldlist, 
       _operation,
       min_sequence
FROM (
  SELECT 'memdep' AS tablename, 
         CONCAT_WS(',',dependant,mem_num) AS primary_key_values, 
         'dependant,mem_num,' AS primary_key_fields, 
         _change_sequence AS min_sequence, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by dependant,mem_num order by _change_sequence) AS rn, 
         _changed_fieldlist, 
         _operation 
  FROM mipbi_ods.memdep
  WHERE mipbi_status = 'NEW'
) main 
WHERE rn = 1 
LIMIT 100
```

In essence what i'm looking for is the records from "memdep" where they have a "mipbi_status" of 'NEW' with the lowest "_change_sequence". Ive tried using a MIN() function instead of the ROW_NUMBER the speed is about the same cost is about 5 more.

Is there a way to reduce the cost/speed of the query. I have around 400 million records in this table if that helps.

Here is the query explained:

```
Limit  (cost=3080.03..3080.53 rows=100 width=109) (actual time=17.633..17.648 rows=35 loops=1)
  ->  Unique  (cost=3080.03..3089.04 rows=1793 width=109) (actual time=17.632..17.644 rows=35 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=3080.03..3084.53 rows=1803 width=109) (actual time=17.631..17.634 rows=36 loops=1)
              Sort Key: (concat_ws(','::text, memdet.mem_num))
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 29kB
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on memdet  (cost=54.39..2982.52     rows=1803 width=109) (actual time=16.853..17.542 rows=36 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: ((mipbi_status)::text = 'NEW'::text)
                    Heap Blocks: exact=8
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_mipbi_status_memdet  (cost=0.00..53.94 rows=1803 width=0) (actual time=10.396..10.396 rows=38 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: ((mipbi_status)::text = 'NEW'::text)
Planning time: 0.201 ms
Execution time: 17.700 ms
```

I'm using a smaller table to show here, this isn't the 400 million record table, but indexes and all will be the same.

Here is the query plan for the large table:

```
Limit  (cost=47148422.27..47149122.27 rows=100 width=113) (actual time=2407976.293..2407977.112 rows=100 loops=1)
  Output: main.tablename, ((main.primary_key_values)::character varying), main.primary_key_fields, main.min_sequence, main._changed_fieldlist, main._operation, main.min_sequence
  Buffers: shared hit=6269554 read=12205028 dirtied=1893 written=4566983, temp read=443831 written=1016025
  ->  Subquery Scan on main  (cost=47148422.27..52102269.25 rows=707692 width=113) (actual time=2407976.292..2407977.100 rows=100 loops=1)
        Output: main.tablename, (main.primary_key_values)::character varying, main.primary_key_fields, main.min_sequence, main._changed_fieldlist, main._operation, main.min_sequence
        Filter: (main.rn = 1)
        Buffers: shared hit=6269554 read=12205028 dirtied=1893 written=4566983, temp read=443831 written=1016025
        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=47148422.27..50333038.19 rows=141538485 width=143) (actual time=2407976.288..2407977.080 rows=100 loops=1)
              Output: 'claim', concat_ws(','::text, claim.gen_claimnum), 'gen_claimnum,', claim._change_sequence, row_number() OVER (?), claim._changed_fieldlist, claim._operation, claim.gen_claimnum
              Buffers: shared hit=6269554 read=12205028 dirtied=1893 written=4566983, temp read=443831 written=1016025
              ->  Sort  (cost=47148422.27..47502268.49 rows=141538485 width=39) (actual time=2407976.236..2407976.905 rows=100 loops=1)
                    Output: claim._change_sequence, claim.gen_claimnum, claim._changed_fieldlist, claim._operation
                    Sort Key: claim.gen_claimnum, claim._change_sequence
                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4588144kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=6269554 read=12205028 dirtied=1893 written=4566983, temp read=443831 written=1016025
                    ->  Seq Scan on mipbi_ods.claim  (cost=0.00..20246114.01 rows=141538485 width=39) (actual time=0.028..843181.418 rows=88042077 loops=1)
                          Output: claim._change_sequence, claim.gen_claimnum, claim._changed_fieldlist, claim._operation
                          Filter: ((claim.mipbi_status)::text = 'NEW'::text)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 356194
                          Buffers: shared hit=6269554 read=12205028 dirtied=1893 written=4566983
Planning time: 8.796 ms
Execution time: 2408702.464 ms
```

Comment: Very often using `distinct on()` instead of window functions is faster in Postgres

Comment: Sorry how does that get me the lowest change sequence value? As i started typing i though this sorry. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: Can we have a *realistic* execution plan? In the one you posted, the sort takes less than 0.1 milliseconds.

Comment: 17ms seems fast enough to me for such a query. How fast do you need that to be?

Comment: I'm generating a query plan on the table with more records that is slow. This is a small table size so this query is pretty slow for the record count. The table in the first query plan only has 107640 records this one coming is 400 million + records.

Comment: The biggest contributor to this is `Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4588144kB` that sorts 88042077 rows on disk. This can only be improved if it could be done in memory - but for that you would need to drastically increase `work_mem` for that query.

Comment: What kind of values are we looking at for `work_mem` ? I have it set to 10mb at the moment. I have access to a large amount of memory on this machine as well.